# Trying to pinpoint 4 coordinates out of a region

Tags: iphone, lua, autotouch

I created a simple macro for Piano Tiles 2 just to see if I could automate it indefinitely.
My code here:

```
search = true
region = {100, 500, 500, 1}
while search do
    findColorTap(0, 1, region);
    findColorTap(258, 1, region);
    findColorTap(16758018, 1, region);
    usleep(5000)
end
```

Works for all three tiles.

```
--0 being jet black notes
--258 being hold notes which have a smaller "hitbox"
--16758018 being extra notes which have an even small "hitbox"
```

Currently the script will check every color on the screen in a 1pixel horizontal line from start to finish (100->500), and when it returns with the color I need, it will tap that pixel once.

I'm curious how to take just 4 points from the region and check those just the same.
I'm also curious if the above is possible, would Lua be able to compile the script faster or slower than checking the region.

My thoughts would be that once findColorTap returns the value I need. The other checks are essentially wasting valuable time. But, I also know that the more intricate the code gets, the harder my phone has to work to process these commands.

I have tried:

Example 1

```
check = true

while check do
    note1 = getColor(80,500)
    note2 = getColor(240,500)
    note3 = getColor(400,500)
    note4 = getColor(560,500)
end

while check do
if note1 == 0 then
    tap(80,500)
elseif note1 == 258 then
    tap(80,500)
elseif note1 == 16758018 then
    tap(80,500)
    else
    end
end
```

This ends up either not reading any notes at all or when it does catch it falls out of sync with the game.

Example 2

```
function fct(startX, maxX, y, increment)
    for x=startX,maxX,160 do
        check=getColor(x,y)
        if check == 0 then
        return(x)
        end
    tap(x,y)
    end
end

v = true
repeat
fct(80,560,500) until
v == false
```

This one was checking correctly and much faster, but was tapping in the wrong locations.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking, how does findColorTap work?

Comment: findColorTap(color, occurrence, region). It will check a variable color that I designate in the code within the region. If the color return matches the color in the code then my phone will simulate a touch on the screen where the color was found. So as these black bars are dropping from top to bottom of my screen, the phone is checking in a line across the x-plane and when one of the bars cross the y(500) then it will be tapped.

Comment: Instead of checking every 'x' from 100 to 600. I just want to check 4 precise pixels for the variable color '0'. But I want it to be more efficient, and that's where it might be trouble.

Comment: @Matthew Why not make the region just one pixel in width and height?

Comment: @warspyking I would need to declare 4 regions because the notes could fall in four spots. But that would strengthen the load on my cpu exponentially. I want to find a way to declare 4 coordinates and check those constantly while tapping if the return value pairs.

Comment: @Matthew you lost me again.

Answer (score 0):

> The other checks are essentially wasting valuable time. But, I also know that the more intricate the code gets, the harder my phone has to work to process these commands.

The "other checks" you're calling are *vastly* more intricate than anything in your code.

You don't need to worry about how many lines of code you have, you need to worry about computationally *expensive* ones being executed a lot.

> would Lua be able to compile the script faster or slower than checking the region.

You mean *run* faster. Compiling is done once on startup, and doesn't affect run speed.

And yes, it will be faster to check 4 pixels than hundreds of pixels.

> I have tried

Saying what you've tried does us no good unless you tell us *why it didn't work*.

> ```
> while check do
>     note1 = getColor(80,500)
>     note2 = getColor(240,500)
>     note3 = getColor(400,500)
>     note4 = getColor(560,500)
> end
>
> while check do
>     if note1 == 0 then
>         tap(80,500)
>     elseif note1 == 258 then
>         tap(80,500)
>     elseif note1 == 16758018 then
>         tap(80,500)
>         else
>         end
>     end
> end
> ```

This looks like it will never leave the first loop (unless you're setting `check` inside `getColor`).

Also, every branch in the second loop produces the exactly same tap.

It's hard to tell what you're asking, but if the goal is to check the color at specified locations, then tap at another specified location depending on the color you found, you could do something like this:

```
-- which points to check
points = {
    { x= 80, y=500 },
    { x=240, y=500 },
    { x=400, y=500 },
    { x=560, y=500 },
}

-- map a found color to a resulting tap point
tapPoints = {
  [0]        = { x=80, y=500 }, -- these
  [258]      = { x=80, y=500 }, --   should
  [16758018] = { x=80, y=500 }, --      be different!
}

while check do
    for checkPoint in ipairs(points) do
        local note = getColor(checkPoint.x, checkPoint.y)
        local tapPoint = tapPoints[note]
        tap(tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y)
    end
end
```

Comment: I like setting the points in a table. That will help. For each [0], [258], etc. should I set the specific points from the table. I would need four tapPoints for each color. Also, I understand everything up until the last block.  Am I missing where you declare checkPoint, and because I honestly cannot comprehend it, what relation does  local note = getColors() and tapPoints[note] have?